# save GUI figure in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

let us consider following program for graphical user interface

```
function varargout = quadratic(varargin)
% QUADRATIC MATLAB code for quadratic.fig
%      QUADRATIC, by itself, creates a new QUADRATIC or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = QUADRATIC returns the handle to a new QUADRATIC or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      QUADRATIC('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in QUADRATIC.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      QUADRATIC('Property','Value',...) creates a new QUADRATIC or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before quadratic_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to quadratic_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help quadratic

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 23-Jul-2014 18:00:48

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @quadratic_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @quadratic_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before quadratic is made visible.
function quadratic_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to quadratic (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for quadratic
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes quadratic wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = quadratic_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in edit1.
function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function edit1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called



function b_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to b (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of b as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of b as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function b_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to b (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function c_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to c (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of c as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of c as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function c_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to c (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

a=str2num(get(handles.a,'String'));
b=str2num(get(handles.b,'String'));
c=str2num(get(handles.c,'String'));
d=b^2-4*a*c;
if (d>0)

     X1=(-b+sqrt(d))/(2*a);
     X2=(-b-sqrt(d))/(2*a);
     set(handles.x1,'String',X1)
      set(handles.x2,'String',X2)

elseif (d==0)

        X1=(-b+sqrt(d))/(2*a);
        set(handles.x1,'String',X1)
      set(handles.x2,'String',X1)
else
     set(handles.x1,'String','roots are complex')
        set(handles.x2,'String','roots are complex')
end
function x1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to x1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of x1 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of x1 as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function x1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to x1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function x2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to x2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of x2 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of x2 as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function x2_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to x2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function a_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to a (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of a as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of a as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function a_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to a (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end
```

this program simple will allow to enter coefficients of quadratic equation and then solve equation and  try to find roots,how can i take screenshot of  GUI interface after this program?please help me,i want to save figure which occurs after running of this program,thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the quick and dirty approaches

```
myGUI = quadratic;
% ......
% do something or wait until it's done...
% ......
print(myGUI, '-dpng', 'GUIOUT.png'); % save as .png
print(myGUI, '-djpeg', 'GUIOUT.jpg'); % save as .jpg
```

It will work fine if you only take a screenshot.

However, if you encounter the problem for which the output picture does not have the same size as the figure on your screen (especially when saving as **pdf**), you will probably have to implement solutions describled in
[this article](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-16WME/).

or even better using [fig2file](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17607-fig2file-m) may work for you.

Comment: i can indicate also jpg format right?could you update for it?

Comment: @dato: Sure you can. Check out [`print`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) fucntion for saving more formats or other input parameters. I also updated the above code for saving jpg.