# how to label lines in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to label each line with unique number in an image. I used this labeling algorithm (given below) but it do not label lines properly. please help. And also the saved image donot shows numbers/label on lines.

**code:**

```
imBin = imread('lines.png');
L = bwlabel(imLines);
s = regionprops(L, 'Centroid');
imwrite(imLines, 'labeled-lines.png');
figure, subplot(1,2,1), imshow(img), title('original image');
subplot(1,2,2), imshow(imLines), title('image with lines');
hold on
for k = 1:numel(s)
    c = s(k).Centroid;
    text(c(1), c(2), sprintf('%d', k), ...
        'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', ...
        'VerticalAlignment', 'middle');
end
hold off
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: What's the issue? I see the labels just fine. It's just that the centroid of shape 1 is in the black region.  Change your label color to red. What is the code to save your image? You should be using `saveas` or something similar and not `imwrite`.

Comment: You should ask [your classmate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067219/text-on-the-objects-in-image-get-disappeared-when-using-imwrite) how to do it

Comment: This question consists of two parts, only the second part is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919041/save-gui-figure-in-matlab?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

The applied function bwlabel will "label" the binary image.

If there is a white connection between any two white pixels they will belong to the same region and therefor get the same label.

The algorithm does not care about any shapes. What is connected belongs together.

So you cannot possibly expect it to give each "line" a separate number if they touch each other.

If you want to get the lines apply Hough transform or something similar.

For the display problem, as already mentioned in the comments and linked answers you just have to change the number-colour and/or move the text position onto the white. You cannot see black numbers on black background.